# How to create ipa file using php

Tags: php, ios, terminal, xcodebuild

I am trying to run shell script from php file to build and archive the ios application. Here is what i have done so far

In my test.php file i have written below code:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("sh build.sh");
?>
```

In build.sh i have written:

```
PROJDIR="/Library/WebServer/Documents/ExpertIPA/IPA/MyApp"
PROJECT_NAME="MyApp"
APPLICATION_NAME="MyApp"
TARGET_SDK="iphonesimulator6.0"
PROJECT_BUILDDIR="${PROJDIR}/build/Release-iphoneos"
TARGET_TEST_NAME="ExpertApp"
BUILD_HISTORY_DIR="${PROJDIR}/ipa/" #where you want the .ipa to go
DEVELOPER_NAME="iPhone Distribution: developer Name"
PROVISONING_PROFILE="/Library/WebServer/Documents/ExpertIPA/IPA/ExpertApp/
MyApp_distribution.mobileprovision"


echo Building Project
cd "${PROJDIR}"
build_type_iOS=$2


xcodebuild clean -configuration "${build_type_iOS}"
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}"  -configuration Release


if [ $? != 0 ]
then
   exit 1
fi

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa"  --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

when i running my build.sh file from terminal it creates MyApp.ipa successfully, also when i am running test.php on mac terminal its working fine, but when i am running test.php from browser it gives following error message.

Error message:

**BUILD NATIVE TARGET MyApp OF PROJECT MyApp WITH CONFIGURATION Release === Check dependencies Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Profile_Name' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains**

Comment: I have same requirement , I have generating the ipa file in MAC system using terminal . But i want generate the ipa file through Linux server using php (Browser)  it is possible . Can you please give the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key & cert xcodebuild is looking for are generally stored in your keychain.  When you're logged in as yourself you can see your keychain with the Keychain Access GUI.  Use that GUI to export the cert and private key.

Then look into using the 'security' command line tool to import the private key & certificate pair that xcodebuild is looking for into the keychain for the _www user.  You may have to actually create a keychain for the _www user (I've only ever done builds with a normal user that you can login as).

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks for something like `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and cannot find it when you run from browser (user `www` or `www-data`)

Comment: Hi Maxim, i didn't understand what you are trying to say, can you please be more specific on ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

Comment: I mean it can look for some specific files in your home directory. When you run from terminal, you run it under your user. When you run it from browser, it is another user with another home directory. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is you private key file. But most likely it looks for iOS certificate (which is in most likely your home dir).

Comment: can you please tell me how to run it from same user using browser

Comment: You need to run web-server from another user, I'll need to search how to do it. Maybe it's better to assign the same home directory for user `_www`. You can edit /etc/passwd file to reassign it, but it also can be "shot in the foot". The third way (and I think the best one) is to symlink certificate and key from your home directory into `/Library/WebServer`

Comment: Also check `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` for directives `User` and `Group` (it will be `_www` and `_www`), you can try to change them to your user/group and restart server. But I haven't tried this so it may cause some troubles.